# Curious results from decltype( std::devlcal<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>() ) when using AppleClang

Tags: c++, c++17, ostream, decltype

## Question

Consider the following struct:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct stream
{
  using type = decltype(
      std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>()
    );
};

template<typename T>
using stream_t = typename stream<T>::type;
```

The "value" of `stream_t<T>` when using certain built-in types (`int`, `float`, ...) for `T` is `std::ostream&`, as I expected.

But when using `std::string`, `char`, `int*`, or some streamable dummy struct for `T`, the type is an rvalue reference, `std::ostream&&`.

Once `std::declval<std::ostream>()` (returns an `std::ostream&&`) is replaced with`std::declval<std::ostream&>` (returns an `std::ostream&`, due to reference collapsing rule, right?) the returned type is the expected `std::ostream&`. Is there some rvalue overload of `operator<<` that I don't know about?

*Why is this happening?*

## Compiler specs

The results above are obtained with **AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033**. When using gcc-7.4 instead, the result is always `std::ostream&`, as expected.

## Complete source

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

/* ************************************
 * Sans reference
 * ************************************ */

template<typename T>
struct stream
{
  using type = decltype(
      std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<T>()
    );
};

template<typename T>
using stream_t = typename stream<T>::type;

/* ************************************
 * With reference
 * ************************************ */

template<typename T>
struct stream_ref
{
  using type = decltype(
      std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()
    );
};

template<typename T>
using stream_ref_t = typename stream_ref<T>::type;

/* ************************************
 * Dummy struct
 * ************************************ */

struct Dummy 
{
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Dummy&);
};

/* ************************************
 * Static asserts
 * ************************************ */

static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<int>,   std::ostream&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<float>, std::ostream&> );

static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<std::string>, std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<const char*>, std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<int*>,        std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<Dummy>,       std::ostream&&> );

static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_ref_t<std::string>, std::ostream&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_ref_t<const char*>, std::ostream&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_ref_t<int*>,        std::ostream&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_ref_t<Dummy>,       std::ostream&> );

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/QCzJN2 . Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: Also provide the compiler where this is happening. Seems pretty weird. I would ask you to try this on multiple compilers.

Comment: @parktomatomi: `T = int*` is supposed to yield `std::ostream&&`, your code asserts equality to `std::ostream&`. Nevertheless, the static assert with ` std::ostream&&` fails as well.

Comment: @Tanveer Badar: I've added the compiler info. I'll try it on another compiler soon.

Comment: @Tanveer Badar: I've tried with gcc-7.4. Here, the result is always `std::ostream&`, i.e. the middle block of `static_asserts` fail, all others pass.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for cleaning up the example. Interestingly, even though you're on apple, I can only reproduce this on MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/d5axNC . clang on Linux still behaves correctly. Weird!

Comment: Nothing fishy in the libcxx (clang) source: https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.38/src/projects/libcxx/include/ostream.auto.html

Comment: Have you tried to compare with `std::invoke_result_t(operator<< <std::ostream, T>, declval<std::ostream>(), declval<T>())`? (I am on mobile otherwise I would do it myself)

Comment: libc++ implements the PR of [LWG1203](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203).

Comment: @T.C. Thank you! Is there a documentation of all issues resolved in libc++? So far, I've only found [this](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html), etc... and none of them seem to go as far back as LWG1023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this behavior is not Apple Clang specific, but common for all modern C++ compilers including GCC, Clang, MSVC, which all accept your program. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8ex6Pc9nb

These checks

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<std::string>, std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<const char*>, std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<int*>,        std::ostream&&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<Dummy>,       std::ostream&&> );
```

are valid because here the global function template returning rvalue-reference:

```
template< class Ostream, class T >
Ostream&& operator<<( Ostream&& os, const T& value );
```

is selected, see (3) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

And these checks

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<int>,   std::ostream&> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<stream_t<float>, std::ostream&> );
```

are satisfied because member functions `basic_ostream<T>::operator<<` are preferred for `int` and `float` arguments, and these member functions return lvalue-reference:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt